# Persisting app configuration in iOS: .plist file vs NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, configuration, version, plist, nsuserdefaults

I have some app-related parameters (boolean and string data) which are either set by user through the app, either at its first execution. I don't want this kind of information to be stored by using `Core Data`, so the options I'm thinking about are:

1) Creating and reading/writing a custom `.plist` file (let's say, `myconfig.plist`) to be stored in `Documents` app folder

2) Saving such info using `NSUserDefaults`

The kind of information I want to keep is, for example, the last app version that was installed and run in order to check if app is being updated, or a flag telling if some specific set of data has been already loaded without having to check the model.

Which of the options would be the most suitable and safest for this task? Or is even there any better option of handling this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this if you would check appstore version with your actually app version https://github.com/nicklockwood/iVersion

Comment: Thanks, I'll consider it though I need to check the current version not only to possibly notify users of a new version availability, but to perform some tasks in my app according to that